# Are there any window manager developed using scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket, chicken-scheme

Now the stumpwm is my every day desktop. It is awesome and i like it VERY much. The stumpwm is developed using common lisp which is a practical FP language.

Scheme is older than common lisp. And it seems there is few applications developed using scheme. Whether or not scheme is just applicative to teaching ?

Regards!

Comment: A simple web search will find you several.  Why don't you try that?  (Sadly, none of them are currently under active development).

Comment: If you count scheme compilers than Chicken Scheme and Racket for example are actively developed

Comment: @jozefg Um, have I misunderstood something here?  Why would you count a compiler as a window manager?  Racket is (or contains) a full scale IDE but that's not the same thing.

Comment: Oh sorry I misread, I thought to OP was simply looking for active Scheme projects, my mistake @itsbruce You're correct here

Comment: Point of order, Mr z_axis: Scheme is **older** than Common Lisp.  Scheme's development was *very* influential on CLISP; the CLISP designers borrowed lexical scope, lexical closures and came damn close to going back to being a LISP1 (they were broadly in favour of it technically but thought it would be too radical a change). Lisp started in the late 50s, Scheme ~ 75-80, Common Lisp ~ 86-94 (roughly)

Comment: @itsbruce, thanks ! It seems there is few application developed using scheme.

Answer (score 1):

How about Sawfish? It's written in a language called `rep` which is its own Scheme-like dialect.

Comment: Using stumpwm i can use swank to do eval anytime. How about Sawfish ? It seems sawfish just use rep to do config.